# Converting char to int without sign bit propagation in C++

Tags: c++, casting

A byte of data is being stored in a 'char' member variable. It should probably be stored as an 'unsigned char' instead, but that can't be changed. I need to retrieve it through an 'int' variable, but without propagating the sign bit.

My solution was this (UINT and UCHAR are the obvious types):

```
void Foo::get_data( int *val )
{
    if( val )
        *val = (int)(UINT)(UCHAR)m_data;  // 'm_data' is type 'char'
}
```

This seemed the best solution to me. I could use

```
*val = 0xff & (int)m_data;
```

instead of the casting, but this doesn't seem as readable. Which alternative is better, if either, and why?

Comment: You left out the most frequently (and arguably most obvious) used: just cast to `unsigned char` and save the result directly to your `int`.

Comment: @WhozCraig : Ah, indeed -- that's appealing. +1. Convert to answer and I will accept.

Comment: Why not just use abs()? It is definitely the cleanest way to do it. It is also likely to be done in the most efficient way possible if you're using a good compiler.

Comment: @patatahooligan : That seems questionable. I suspect the argument to abs() will be converted to int incorrectly in the first place, which I was trying to avoid, won't it? Also, why use a library call just to do that? <runs away screaming>

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "without propagating the sign bit" means then? I assumed you want only absolute value of m_data. What you are doing will return 256-m_data. If you want to read the value stored as though it were an unsigned char, try reinterpret_cast<unsigned char&>m_data.

Answer (score 2):

Just write

```
*val = (UCHAR)m_data;
```

As now the expression `(UCHAR)m_data` has an unsigned type neither sign bit will be propagated.

Answer (score 2):

The type of conversion here is [Integral promotion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion).

When promoting to a wider integer type the value is always "widened" using its signedness, so that the sign is propagated to the new high order bits for signed values. To avoid the sign propagation convert a signed value to its corresponding unsigned type first.

You can do that with an explicit `*val = static_cast<UCHAR>(m_data)`.

---

Or, safer, using `as_unsigned` function as `*val = as_unsigned(m_data)`. Function `as_unsigned` looks like:

```
inline unsigned char as_unsigned(char a) { return a; }
inline unsigned char as_unsigned(unsigned char a) { return a; }
inline unsigned char as_unsigned(signed char a) { return a; }
// And so on for the rest of integer types.
```

Using `as_unsigned` eliminates the risk of that explicit cast becoming incorrect after maintenance, should `m_data` become a wider integer it will use another overload of `as_unsigned` automatically without requiring the maintainer to manually update the expression. The inverse function `as_signed` is also useful.

Answer (score 1):

The cast is better because some compilers (eg. clang) actually generate extra code for the bitwise and. Of course, you only need the one cast to `unsigned char`.

The cast also expresses your intent better: the data is actually an unsigned char that you move to an int. So I would call it better even with compilers which generate the same code.